# Where to Store purchased very huge files >200MB on iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, download, storage, nsfilemanager

Where i have to store downloaded huge files on iOS?
the file is more then 200MB.
Is **< Application_Home >/Library/Caches** the right directory for it?

The file is downloaded after in app purchase and should remain in the App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After iCloud is implemented in Apple, The Document directory data is somehow related with iCloud Storage. Hence Apple is now rejecting the applications using heavy data storage in document directory.

You need to store the data at some other location. Store the PDF & Other Artwork file At some other location.

This link May Help You.

https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/

I Hope this helps.